# The Canonical Bundle over a Riemann Surface

Tags: differential-geometry, riemann-surfaces, vector-bundles

I am trying to understand an example of a line bundle over a Riemann surface; as it is very terse and short, I have lots of trouble. It is written in block-quotes below, and I ask questions as I go.

> The *canonical bundle* $K$ over a Riemann surface $M$ is the cotangent bundle, or the bundle of holomorphic $1$-forms. Suppose we have local coordinates $z$ and $w$ with
>   $$
> w(z) = \phi_\beta \circ \phi_\alpha^{-1} (z)
> $$
>   a function of $z$ on the overlap.

**Question 1:** What is meant by "with $w(z) = \phi_\beta \circ \phi_\alpha^{-1} (z)$ a function of $z$ on the overlap"? Why is it a function of $z$? I don't understand this equation at all.

> The $1$-forms $dz$ and $dw$ give local trivializations of the canonical bundle, and on the overlap
>   $$
> dw = w'dz.
> $$

**Question 2:** how are $dz$ and $dw$ are local trivializations? Isn't $dz$ at a point a map from the tangent space to $\mathbb{C}$? And how is this relation obtained?

> Therefore the transition functions are $dw/dz$, where $w = \phi_\beta \circ \phi_\alpha^{-1}$.

**Question 3:** What does "dw/dz" even mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many abuses of language in this  subject and in order to help you I'll describe a few things completely rigorously.

Let $(U,\phi_\alpha)$ and $(V,\phi_\beta)$ be two charts (=local coordinates)  of your Riemann surface $X$ at $P\in X$, that is $P\in U\cap V$.
The overlap is $\phi_\alpha(U\cap V)\subset \mathbb C$ and you have a holomorphic isomorphism $w: \phi_\alpha(U\cap V)\to \phi_\beta(U\cap V):z\mapsto w(z)$ which answers Question 1.

If you define  $z_0=z(P)$, you can compute the derivative $w'(z_0)=\frac {dw}{dz}(z_0)\in \mathbb C$ and this answers Question 3.

Finally, since a holomorphic function $\mathbb \phi$  defined in a neighbourhood of  $P$ has a  differential which is a   linear form  $d\phi(P):T_P(X)\to \mathbb C$, you get two linear forms $d{\phi_\alpha} (P),d{\phi_\beta} (P):T_P(X)\to \mathbb C$.
Are they equal? Not at all! They are related by $$d{\phi_\beta} (P)=w'(z_0)\cdot d{\phi_\alpha}(P) \in T_P^*(X)$$
an equality in the fiber of the cotangent bundle at $P$ which answers (I hope!) your  Question 2.

Comment: Yes, thank you! This has made things a lot clearer!